# Set Interval is not running in background when using workerTimers

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I have developed a countdown timer using setInterval. But, it's getting paused in some cases (When keeping the browser tab or browser window in the background), hence not accurate. So, I used [worker-timers](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/worker-timers), but it failed for iOS devices when kept in the background.

Is there any standard method to achieve javascript timers working accurately in the background?

**Sample Demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/worker-timers-guske?file=/src/App.js